# How can I delete a Service Plan in Azure that has no Services attached

Tags: azure, azure-service-plan

I want to delete a service plan in azure, but it shows me the error that the service plan is attached by a App Service. "Only empty App Service Plans can be deleted".

The Overview of the service plan shows 0/0. Is this a bug in azure and what is the workaround?

Comment: Try the powershell `Remove-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name <name> -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup>`

Comment: Some times I have found that the UI updates and shows 0 services/apps but it takes up to 24 hours for the plan to be delete-able.

Comment: I had an app service plan with no services that I couldn't delete (no delete button shown). Even leaving it over 24 hours and doing hard-refresh it didn't go away but just closing the window and opening it again it was gone

Answer (score 0):

I would try to delete the service plan using PowerShell using the [Remove-AzureRmAppServicePlan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/remove-azurermappserviceplan?view=azurermps-6.0.0) cmdlet. Example:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Remove-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-WestUS" -Name "ContosoASP"
```

**Note:** If you have access to more then one subscription with the accout you login, you have to select the desired subscription first using the `Select-AzureRmSubscription` cmdlet.